# Read lines from an input file of varying line sizes

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, getline, fileinputstream

Currently, I am using getline to read lines from a file and I can access individual characters the following way from stdin:

```
char buffer[1024];
while((lineSize = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
            if (line[0] != 84) {
                // ...
                continue; // continue to next line in file
            }
            if (line[0] == 84){ // (the 'T' character)
                printf("TEST: Line Value: %s\n", line);
                buffer[0] = line[1]; // this is a single digit number in char form
                buffer[1] = '\0';
                // send buffer somewhere
                send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                // ...
}
```

A sample file is as follows:

```
T3
T9
S0
S4
T55
T6
```

However, as you can see, I run into issues when a number > 9 is given such as the T55 line here. I can only grab the first digit with this method. Therefore, I may have to completely redo the way I read a file. **Is there a better and simple way I can read through an input file and check the first character and make the remaining character(s) into an int until the end of a line?** (Max the integer can be is 100 btw)

Comment: When you read and write with `getline()` (or any other character input function) you are reading a character-at-a-time. So `"T55"` is `{ 'T', '5', '5', '\0' }`. So using `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]` only reads `'T'` into `buffer`. Also, don't use `84` when you mean `'T'`, use `'T'`. You want to use `sscanf (line, " %c%d", &somechar, &someint) == 2` -- validating both conversions take place. Then you have `'T'` in `somechar` variable and your `int` in the `someint` variable.

Comment: Also, while `getline()` is fine, for what you are reading `fgets()` will work as well and is standard C instead of POSIX.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am confused as to how both ```buffer[0]``` and ```buffer[1]``` has 'T'. T would be stored in ```buffer[0]``` while ```buffer[1]``` would contain '5'.

Comment: No. In your code, `buffer[1] = '\0';` so `buffer[1]` is always the *nul-terminating* character `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comments, you can use `fgets()` to read `line` and then use `sscanf()` with the format string of `" %c%d%n"` to extract the first character and converting the next set of digits to an `int` and finally obtaining to total number of characters consumed by `sscanf()` in that conversion using the `"%n"` specifier. You validate that both the character and integer conversion took place and that the first non-whitespace character read was `'T'`. You can then use `mychar` and `myint` as desired and use `mylen` as the length to use with `send`.

(**note:** you can scan forward in `line` to determine if any whitespace was included at the beginning and ignore than in your call to `send()` -- that is left to you)

Putting it altogether, you can so something like:

```c
  char line[1024],
       mychar = 0;
  int myint = 0,
      mylen;
  
  /* read using fgets */
  while (fgets (line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    /* parse with sscanf, validate both conversions and 'T' as 1st char,
     * use "%n" to get number of chars through int conversion
     */
    if (sscanf (line, " %c%d%n", &mychar, &myint, &mylen) != 2 || 
                mychar != 'T') {
      fputs ("error: invalid format.\n", stderr);
      continue;
    }
    
    send (clientSocket, line, mylen, 0);    /* send mylen chars */
  }
```

To be more specific, I will need to see your [Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ensure there is nothing outside what you have posted that will impact the code above.

---

**Adding Example**

Adding a short example to show the result of parsing under expected and unexpected input with the above, and adding the scanning forward to remove leading whitespace in the line, a short program that reads input from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`, outputting the lines matching `'T'(int)`, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {

  char line[1024],
       mychar = 0,
       nl = '\n';
  int myint = 0,
      mylen;
  
  /* read using fgets */
  while (fgets (line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    char *p = line;
    /* parse with sscanf, validate both conversions and 'T' as 1st char,
     * use "%n" to get number of chars through int conversion
     */
    if (sscanf (line, " %c%d%n", &mychar, &myint, &mylen) != 2 || 
        mychar != 'T') {
      fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid format: %s", line);
      continue;
    }
    
    while (isspace (*p)) {    /* reamove leading whitespace */
      p += 1;
      mylen -= 1;
    }
    
    // send (clientSocket, p, mylen, 0);    /* send mylen chars */
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, p, mylen);
    write (STDOUT_FILENO, &nl, 1);
  }
}
```

(**note:** `write (STDOUT_FILENO, &nl, 1);` is simply included above to output a newline after each output -- it would not be part of what you `send()` over your socket -- unless the receiving program is using the `'\n'` as the line termination character)

Example Input File:

```
$ cat dat/charint.txt
T4
T44
T444
 TT
 T3 and more gibberish
P55
```

(**note:** leading whitespace and trailing characters included in last two lines beginning with `'T'`, including the invalid line format `" TT"`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/charandintsend < dat/charint.txt
T4
T44
T444
error: invalid format:  TT
T3
error: invalid format: P55
```

Let me know if you have questions, or if I misunderstood some aspect of your question.

Comment: This is amazing , especially the ```sscanf``` trick of picking off values is nice and I am trying to implement that and the ```fgets``` way right now. One question I have for the ```sscanf``` error checking is what does the != 2 mean? I have seen ```< 0``` or ```!=-1``` for input checking etc but never that value.

Comment: `sscanf()` returns the *match count* for each successful conversion. `"%c"` is one match + `"%d"` == 2 matches. (`"%n"` does NOT contribute to the match-count). So if `sscanf(..) != 2` you don't have 2 successful conversions indicating you did not read a `char` and `int`.

Comment: Pedantic: `isspace (*p)` s/b `isspace (*((unsigned char*)p))`.  Alternative: `sscanf (line, " %n%c%d%n", &n1, &mychar, &myint, &mylen); mylen -= n1; ...`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica nice use of `n1`. I considered the `unsigned char` requirement, but reading normal input from `stdin` should be limited to ASCII (absent some really strange character set, or the intentional copy of a unicode character to the input). But the point chux makes is valid, the parameter type for all `ctype.h` functions is `unsigned char`. (and when he says "Pedantic", he's not talking about `-pedantic` which is fine as written, he's talking about really being "*Pedantic*"). Favorite def: "Overly concerned with trivial details."